# Reveal Modal display only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popup, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation modal to make popup. How can i modify this code, so the pop up only appear one time per user a day. Thanks

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open')});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to not open multiple times in a single page view, you could add a class to prevent reopen. Note the use of the `:not` selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#myModal:not(.opened)').foundation('reveal', 'open')}).addClass('opened');
```

If you want to prevent the modal from opening more than once within a time period, check out this MDN example on how to set a cookie with an expiration time, where `doSomethingOnlyOnce` is the name of the cookie you're inserting and later can check for in document.cookie.

```
function doOnce() {
  if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
  }
}
```

You'd want to replace the `alert()` call with your code, and also generate the date programatically for the `expires` attribute of the cookie string.

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie